# How to give a gray color to the header of a listview

Tags: c, listview, winapi

In a dialogbox win32 API application, I put a listview.

The header of this listview stay white.

How to give it a gray 3D look as I can see it everywhere ?

Thank you !! :-)

An picture of the result I want to get :

[image: Picture]

Comment: Please show a picture. How could the header be white?

Comment: Sorry : I add it into my question.

Comment: The white header is the standard Windows 10 look, why would you want to change it ?The look on your second picture is the old pré Windows XP look that is nowadays only visible on legacy software. Otherwise you can use a custom draw hader for your header, but that's another story.

Comment: If you want to make it ugly like that then look for this string in your project or manifest file: `'Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0'` comment out the whole line or remove it.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: that will disable themes for the entire app. You could alternatively use `SetWindowTheme()` to disable themes on just the ListView by itself.

Comment: Oh ! You all show me a way I didn't imagine. I understand that my answer was silly. Sorry ! And thank you all for your kindness !!

Comment: @RemyLebeau it works different in Windows 10